# Quickly find the cardinality of an elliptic curve

Tags: elliptic-curves

Let $(E:y^2=x^3+ax+b) $ on $\mathbb F_q$, with $ q \mod 2=1$.

If $\gcd(3,q-1)=1$ and $a=0$, then it's easy to find the cardinality of the curve $E$ : $|E|=q$.

> Are there an another conditions on $(q, a, b)$, where it's easy to find $|E|$?

Answer (score 4):

The other famous family of this phenomenon is when $b=0$ and $q$ is a prime such that $q\equiv 3\pmod 4$. In this case the number of points is $q+1$. See this [theorem whose proof is in Washington's book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_primality#Group_structure_of_E(FN)).

Both are special cases of a wider theory of [elliptic curves with complex multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_multiplication) (specifically these curves have complex multiplication by $\omega$ and $i$ where $\omega^2+\omega+1=0$ and $i^2+1=0$). CM methods allow us to create curves with a specified number of points and are often used in pairing based cryptography.